# Auto populating Set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, auto-populate

Is there anything like `AutoPopulatingList` but for `Set`?
The data that I want to show is an association that uses `Set`.

```
public class Employer implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet();
}
```

I've tried using `AutoPopulatingList` but in that case I have to use `List` in hibernate which needs me to specify `list-index` using `Employee.employeeId` and whenever I retrieve the `employees` through `Employee` later the list would have spaces between element (`null` elements) depending on the `Employee.employeeId`.

I need to auto-populate the collection because I need to generate the `employees` dynamically while creating the `Employer`.
I got the following when I use plain `Set`:
`org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'employees[0]' of bean class [model.Employer]: Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'employees[0]'`

Is there any other solution?

**Edit**

I'm trying to implement dynamic form

Comment: Are you trying to do dynamic forms? Or what are you trying to achieve by this approach?

Comment: @PavelHoral exactly, dynamic forms. However I dont think I can use `List` as if I use `List` with `Employee.employeeId` as the index in the HBM file, the list would have spaces between element (element with `null` value) whenever I retrieve it later from database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `Set` as a binding target in MVC because it is not possible to create property path for its items.

### What you should use

You should use `Map<Integer, YourType>` when building dynamic forms. What we have implemented many times (so I know it is working) is this:

- a simple number sequence is used as keys without any connection to the actual items
- the key sequence is always increasing but doesn't need to be continuous (e.g. in case user will delete the second item, you will end up with `1, 3, 4, ...` )
- if you want to add another item, you just find the highest number and then add form indexed with `maxIndex + 1` (always increasing sequence)
- the `Map` implementation **MUST BE** instance of `LinkedHashMap` so that the iteration order is preserved (Spring is creating this implementation by default if a `Map` field needs to be autopopulated)
- the `Map` must be part of some parent form object (i.e. you can not have `Map` as the top form object) so that Spring is able to infer the generic types from the property getter

---

### View and JavaScript implementation example

There are many ways how you can work with this. For example we have a special *template subform*, which is used when we need to dynamically add another subform. This approach is probably a bit more complex to follow:

```
<form:form action="${formUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute="organizationUsersForm">
    <%-- ... other fields ... --%>
    <div id="userSubforms">
        <c:forEach items="${organizationUsersForm.users.entrySet()}" var="subformEntry">
            <div data-subform-key="${subformEntry.key}">
                <spring:nestedPath path="users['${subformEntry.key}']">
                    <%@ include file="user-subform.jspf" %>
                </spring:nestedPath>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addSubform(jQuery('#userSubforms'), 'users', 'user', 'userTemplate');">ADD ANOTHER USER</button>
    <%-- other form fields, submit, etc. --%>
</form:form>

<div class="hide" data-subform-template="user">
    <spring:nestedPath path="userTemplate">
        <%@ include file="user-subform.jspf" %>
    </spring:nestedPath>
</div>

<script>
    function addSubform(subformContainer, subformPath, templateName, templatePath) {
        // Find the sequence number for the new subform
        var existingSubforms = subformContainer.find("[data-subform-key]");
        var subformIndex = (existingSubforms.length != 0) ?
                parseInt(existingSubforms.last().attr("data-subform-key"), 10) + 1 : 0;
        // Create new subform based on the template
        var subform = jQuery('<div data-subform-key="' + subformIndex + '" />').
                append(jQuery("[data-subform-template=" + templateName + "]").children().clone(true));
        // Don't forget to update field names, identifiers and label targets
        subform.find("[name]").each(function(node) {
            this.name = subformPath + "["+ subformIndex +"]." + this.name;
        });
        subform.find("[for^=" + templatePath + "]").each(function(node) {
            this.htmlFor = this.htmlFor.replace(templatePath + ".", subformPath + "["+ subformIndex +"].");
        });
        subform.find("[id^=" + templatePath + "]").each(function(node) {
            this.id = this.id.replace(templatePath + ".", subformPath + "["+ subformIndex +"].");
        });
        // Add the new subform to the form
        subformContainer.append(subform);
    }
</script>
```

Now you can ask *"How can user delete a subform"*? This is pretty easy if the subform JSPF contains:

```
<button onclick="jQuery(this).parents('[data-subform-key]').remove();">DELETE USER</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set isn't an indexed collection, you can only bind indexed collections or arrays. You might try with a LinkedHashSet (that one has a guaranteed order, whereas HashSet doesn't) or use List implementations for binding the values.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot get element with index 0".. sets are not indexed based to begin with..

<s>why don't you use LazyList of Employee..</s> as correctly pointed out by @PavelHoral we don't need to use LazyList as Spring handles it.. a simple List initialization (like new ArrayList()) would do, albeit with the possibility of having spaces(nulls) when user submits non-continuous elements.

```
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Comment: Is that compatible with `Set`? because If I use `List` and I use `Employee.employeeId` in `list-index` whenever I retrieve the `employees` through the `Employer` later the `employee` `List` would have `null` element between them depending on `Employee.employeeId`

Comment: from LazyList's documentation- "Returns a "lazy" list whose elements will be created on demand.", so whenever you get/access any Employee, if it doesn't exist it'll return the instance created inside `create()` method.. 
"compatible with Set"- Set's are Data structure used when user wants to maintain uniqueness in datastructure, you can achieve the same effect using EployeeId in list-index..

Comment: so yes there will be spaces(null) in between, but using LazyList, if you try to access those null places a newly created object would be returned.

Comment: But then if I go with that implementation, when I iterate over the `List` it would create a new instance of empty `Employee` every time it finds a `null` object which later also would cause the object to be shown on the web page as well

Comment: you should not be passing in the 'Employer' model directly to the form jsp, so now you can map using Set<Employee> in 'Employer' and persist that using hibernate.. and than create a projection class(form) which has List<Employee> using Employer Model and pass it to-and-fro between user interactions, also now List index won't be Employee id, but some integer depending on the order you inserted in the list.. and after user submits the form you can iterate the List to rule out the possible empty values(check for some field of Emplyee which can't possibly be null like- id)

Comment: @verdy also iterating a LazyList won't create an infinite list, because we only iterate till the length of the List.

Comment: Spring is able to infer generic collection type from a property getter. Also `BeanWrapperImpl` is able to autogrow collections itself so there is no need for such constructs as `LazyList`... let these obsolete constructs peacefully die :).

Comment: @PavelHoral i tried `<c:forEach items="${organizationUsersForm.users.entrySet()}"` but i am getting an error - the function entrySet must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified, i agree that LazyList is not necessary here because of Spring and one could simply use new ArrayList() or any other type of List collection.

Comment: @VaibhavBehl if you are getting error calling functions from EL, then you have old EL version. This is supported from version 2.2. Upgrading to newer servlet container might help.