# How to bind Maps of Maps, or some other way to structure the data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am not even sure how to go about asking this, but I will try to give it a shot.

I have an existing application that I support that consists of a dynamically generated form of a bunch of values.  The form is broken into a matrix of rows and columns, and the JSP uses this information to construct the required form:inputs.  To build the form I have some Java classes like such (mostly pseudo code just so you get an idea as to what I am doing):

```
class Form {
  List<FormParts> parts;
}

class FormParts {
  List<FormRow> rows;
  List<FormHeader> headers;
}

class FormRow {
  String name;
}

class FormHeader {
  String name;
}
```

I use these classes to dynamically build the form in the JSP by looping through the FormParts, then using the FormRows and FormHeaders to build a table of form:inputs, using a counter to index the resulting answers List described here in the FormResponse:

```
class FormResponse {
  List<FormAnswer> answers;
}

class FormAnswer {
  int rowNumber;
  int headerNumber;
  String value;
}
```

The problem I am having is the `List<FormAnswer> answers`.  Because it's a List I have to store all the Answers, even the empty ones (nulls), in order to be able to provide the ability to reload the FormResponses from the DB.  This is creating a HUGE amount of junk rows in my table, and making the application slow.  When I first wrote this about 4 months ago, however, I remember I struggled for some time trying to figure out how to make Spring MVC bind to a Map of Maps, which would be a MUCH better way to implement this since I could simply skip the answers I don't need.  I remember the problem was that, internally in Spring MVC, those Lists and Maps become LazyList and LazyMap.

Does anyone have another possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer on dynamic forms with Spring here at [Auto populating Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002027/auto-populating-set/17007161#17007161) .

The key is to use `Map<Integer, YourObject>` instead of lists. With that you can have gaps in your indexes.

Using Map of Maps is not possible, because the generics will be erased. **The map always need to be property of object**. So your example should be OK.

Concept of LazyList / LazyMap is long dead. Spring is capable of manipulating [any list and map type](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.java#L867). If the Map property is null, an instance of `LinkedHashMap` is [created](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.java#L636) by [default](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/CollectionFactory.java#L205).

---

Other possibility is to do your binding and validation manually and just send JSON via the wire (i.e. submit your form as JSON in `<input type="hidden">` or directly via AJAX).

Comment: The problem I am running into is that we are stuck on Spring 3.06 right now.  I tried switching the answers list over to a Hashmap, but then it starts puking with "org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'answers[0]' of bean class [com.xxx.domain.FormResponse]: Could not determine property type for auto-growing a default value".  I am going to try and implement a custom LazyMap and see if that will help.

Comment: That is not necessary. This is not a new feature. Check your `autogrowNestedPaths` property of `WebDataBinder`. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/v3.0.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.java#L131

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. The exception actually says that Spring tried to auto-grow your collection. However it was unable to determine the type of the collection entry. **Your generics are probably not correct.**