# spring mvc form inputs

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I  m having a hard time working with array inputs for example how can I:

1. Write the following html input using spring form tag:

`<input name="phone []"/>
 <input name="phone[]"/>`

I tried
`<form:input path="phone []"/>` 
but no luck throws error saying that class attribute phone [] does not exists.

2 . After you tell me how to do step 1 how can i repopulate the form with user inputs values using @ModelAttribute  In case of validation error. Obviously normal using of `<spring:input path="phone"/>` won't work cause phone has a list of values.

By the way I use controller with annotations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends if you are trying to do dynamic forms or just a static list based forms. For static ones - you need to iterate manually:

```
<c:forEach items="myModel.phones" varStatus="status">
    <form:input path="phones[${status.index}]" />
</c:forEach>
```

Dynamic forms are a little bit complicated and you should try google as this was asked and answered few times.

Comment: So for example if I have two phones inputs, in my ModelClass i need to have ` List<String> phones; `  and then to add two empty values in the list to make foreach iteration work ?  ` phones.add("") and phones.add() ? , Isn't there a better way to initialize myModel.phones ?

Comment: You don't need to initialise the list if you have a predefined set of elements - `<c:forEach begin="0" end="1">`. Spring will handle non-existing list entries. With some expression language you can even do a bit more advanced condition `end="${myModel.phones.size() < 2 ? 2 : myModel.phones.size()}"`. If you want to get really advanced, you will probably need to use Map, instead of List.

Comment: You can check my answer here on dynamic forms - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002027/auto-populating-set/17007161#17007161 . I don't claim this is the best way, but I am using this approach a lot. But as I wrote, this is a bit more complicated than the simple List approach.