# Spring MVC One to Many Form Submission

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a class "**Info**" that has users' Information like name, dob, email.

I also have another class called "**Address**" that has users' address information.

**The Info class has One to Many relationship with the Address**. So the Info class has a list of Address. eg: List < Address > addList;

Now I want to have a form so that the users can put their information. In the form, the users gonna input their Info class information and Address class information. I tried to create a jsp page that  takes all the parameter from the user but I am getting errors on this jsp page.

```
<c:forEach items="info.addList" var="address" varStatus="status">

  <div class="form-group" > 
    <form:label path="address.address1">Street Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="address.address1" cssClass="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="address.address2">Apt/Suite</form:label>
    <form:input path="address.address2" cssClass="form-control"/>
  <div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="address.city">City</form:label>
    <form:input path="address.city" cssClass="form-control"/>
  </div>
</c:forEach>


org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'address' of bean class     [  com.ttg.mvc.beans.Info]: Bean property 'address' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
```

So here is the Info Class:

```
other properties................
private String gender;
@Column(name = "dob")
private String dob;
@Column(name = "ssn")
private String ssn;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Sales> salesList;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Address> addlist;
```

Address Class:

```
other properties..........
private String country;
@Column(name = "zipcode")
private String zipcode;
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Info userId;
```

And this is the request mapping for that url to display the registration form

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    Info info= new Info();
    model.addAttribute("info", info);
    return "registration";
}
```

Comment: please put your error, @Robinsion Rossi

Comment: show us your code for Info and Address, i think the issue is there

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17007161/865403 (how to implement dynamic subforms which is the same as having one-to-many relations in one form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jsp code should be something like below, since `Address` is a collection, so we need to work with `index`. The index will be dynamic since the user can add more address or either way you want to maintain it.

```
<c:forEach items="info.addList" var="address" varStatus="status">

  <div class="form-group" > 
    <form:label path="address[0].address1">Street Name</form:label>
    <form:input path="address[0].address1" cssClass="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="address[0].address2">Apt/Suite</form:label>
    <form:input path="address[0].address2" cssClass="form-control"/>
  <div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="address[0].city">City</form:label>
    <form:input path="address[0].city" cssClass="form-control"/>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the same error response as mentioned above

Comment: Both of you guys are right. Before sending model object of Info to the JSP, I just needed to add a list of address in the Info class. And that list contains one new object of Address class. It's bit of work but works fine now. And I use the mentioned guidance and perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Address is Collection , you have to access with the help of index on JSP.

```
<c:forEach items="info.addList" var="address" varStatus="status">

      <div class="form-group" > 
        <form:label path="address[status.index].address1">Street Name</form:label>
        <form:input path="address[status.index].address1" cssClass="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="address[status.index].address2">Apt/Suite</form:label>
        <form:input path="address[status.index].address2" cssClass="form-control"/>
      <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form:label path="address[status.index].city">City</form:label>
        <form:input path="address[status.index].city" cssClass="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the same error response as mentioned above

Comment: Both of you guys are right. Before sending model object of Info to the JSP, I just needed to add a list of address in the Info class. And that list contains one new object of Address class. It's bit of work but works fine now. And I use the mentioned guidance and perfect. Thanks!